# How to save every output data in loop by python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Today i found problem in my python dict. I need to collect  all output data from loop and write it in json file. Process of writing works well, but, as result, inside json file only one, last output. How i should fix part of my code with dictionary? Here is code:

```
def classify(sess, label_list, softmax_output, coder, images, image_file):

print('Running file %s' % image_file)
image_batch = make_batch(image_file, coder, not FLAGS.single_look)
batch_results = sess.run(softmax_output, feed_dict={images:image_batch.eval()})
output = batch_results[0]
batch_sz = batch_results.shape[0]
for i in range(1, batch_sz):
    output = output + batch_results[i]

output /= batch_sz
best = np.argmax(output)
best_choice = (label_list[best], output[best])
Guess = 'Guess @ 1 %s, prob = %.2f' % best_choice
print('Guess @ 1 %s, prob = %.2f' % best_choice)
faces_pred = dict()
faces_pred =  {"face_pred": Guess}
with open('pred.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump( faces_pred, fp)

nlabels = len(label_list)
if nlabels > 2:
    output[best] = 0
    second_best = np.argmax(output)

    print('Guess @ 2 %s, prob = %.2f' % (label_list[second_best], output[second_best]))
return best_choice
```

I am interesting only in all output's of Guess 1! 
Thank you for your time :3

UPD---------
Inside json file, after run my program, have this output:

```
{"face_pred": "Guess @ 1 (60, 100), prob = 0.75"}
```

That's correct, but only for one face (i have 3+ Guess @ 1). It's not adding new data in json file, just rewriting it!

UPD2--------
How it looks like is console:

- Running file ./frontal-face-1.jpg
- Running multi-cropped image
- Guess @ 1 (60, 100), prob = 0.95
- Guess @ 2 (4, 6), prob = 0.02
- Running file ./frontal-face-2.jpg
- Running multi-cropped image
- Guess @ 1 (60, 100), prob = 0.75
- Guess @ 2 (38, 43), prob = 0.12
- ubuntu@ubuntu122:~/roman/IWAdector$

Comment: this `output = output + batch_results[i]` is the only command in a loop anywhere in your program, and it is not a dictionary.... so you have to explain more

Comment: Dict. is this part: faces_pred = dict()
faces_pred =  {"face_pred": Guess}
with open('pred.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump( faces_pred, fp)

Comment: you have exactly one update to that dict, as stated in `faces_pred =  {"face_pred": Guess}`, it is not in a loop, so there is no reason to think it will get more than one value. rethink your program structure and think where you can loop to get multiple values

Comment: I am new in coding, and but this part of code using with every picture what i have. I made update of my main post, watch please. If i will open  pred.json at the start, i can see how it's changing at the first line. It's add Guess from first picture, but after rewrite it on the Guess from next picture. And after it rewrite on next. Only data from last picture will be in it. That's question - what the way to add all data, like list, without rewriting on the first line of json file.

Comment: now i get it, posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your comments i now understand your problem... you open your file like this:

```
with open('pred.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump( faces_pred, fp)
```

and that rewrites the entire file each time, so you only get the last result there

you could do this instead:

```
with open('pred.json', 'a') as fp:
    data_to_write = json.dumps(faces_pred)
    fp.write(faces_pred + '\n')
```

notice 2 things i did here:

1. I opened the file with the 'a' flag and not 'w', that is used for appending to the end of the file each time instead of rewriting the file
2. I used `json.dumps` instead of `json.dump` to produce a string, and then wrote that string (appended it) to the file, with `\n` at the end to ensure it will break the line after each time

Comment: Thank you very much for it! It work's well, but at the last like we should write fp.write(data_to_write + '\n')!

Comment: If it's possible, what i should add to rewrite all my file, if i am working with new video\set of images?

Comment: Basically, w flag will rewrite, a flag appends at the end